# How to adjust brightness vaio nr21s ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: nvidia, brightness, vaio

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my `Vaio nr21s` but cannot adjust brightness levels. The <kbd>fn</kbd> keys work, but they don't change a thing, brightness remains at max level.

Thought I should choose a repository nvidia driver, but I believe it makes it worse, because the screens during boot are all messed up. So I got back to the nouveau.

Video card is `nvidia 8400m gt` gpu.

I know that there are plenty of threads stating the same issues, but none of the suggested solutions worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

### I faced the same problem as you are facing. But NOW it is fixed..

TO fix this follow this steps..

Open terminal(Press Ctrl + Alt +T)
and Type

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

press enter, and then type

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will find this line in the new opened window:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

### Restart your system..

Comment: hi, i edited the file just like you said, and brightness still not changing. i'm using the gallium driver.

Comment: did you typed 'sudo update-grub' and then restarted?
If yes but still not working then foollow my next answer..

Answer (score 0):

If above fix didn't work then repeat same steps but..

this time try to change the above mentioned line with:

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"**

then same steps and restart then reply me did it helped or not??

Comment: nothing. still no changes in brightness.

Comment: no help? :(((((